# Hash table "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation"

Tags: c, hashtable

we're trying to set up a hash table and some procedures that will set, get and delete values from the table. We're encountering the "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values(s)" problem on line 35 and 53.

```
==23720== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==23720==    at 0x400CF6: hash (hashserver.c:35)
==23720==    by 0x400D49: set (hashserver.c:53)
==23720==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==23720==    at 0x40112A: main (hashserver.c:133)
```

In case there's a collision in the hash table, we're using separate chaining with linked list. Could you help? Thanks!

```
typedef struct KeyVal {
    unsigned char* value;
    unsigned char* key;
    struct KeyVal* next;
}KeyVal;

unsigned long hash (unsigned char *str)
{
  unsigned long hash = 5381;
  int c;

  (line 35) -> while (c = *str++)
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;    /* hash * 33 + c */

  return hash%MAXHASHTABLEN;
}

int set(KeyVal *hashtable[], unsigned char* key, unsigned char* value){
 (line 53)->   unsigned long hval = hash(key);

    if(hashtable[hval] == NULL){
        KeyVal* runvar = calloc(1, sizeof(KeyVal));
        runvar->key = key;
        runvar->value = value;
        runvar->next = NULL;
        hashtable[hval] = runvar;
        fprintf(stdout, "Successful set 1\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
    KeyVal* counter = hashtable[hval];
    KeyVal* prev = counter;
    while(counter!= NULL){
        prev = counter;
        counter = counter->next;
    }
        KeyVal* runvar = calloc(1, sizeof(KeyVal));
        runvar->key = key;
        runvar->value = value;
        runvar->next = NULL;
        prev->next = runvar;
        fprintf(stdout, "Successful set 2\n");
        return 2;
    }
    return -1;
}

(line 133) -> int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sock, new, status, command;
    struct addrinfo hints, *serverinfo, *p; 
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; 
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]; 
    unsigned int numbytes = 0;
    char buffer[128];
    int line, transid, bitcounter = 0;
    unsigned short keylenMSB, keylenLSB, keylen, vallenMSB, vallenLSB, vallen = 0;
    KeyVal *hashtable[MAXHASHTABLEN];
}
```

It's an exercise with the use of RPC and we receive the command from the client in this way. At the very end we call the set() function:

```
unsigned char keybuf[MAXBUFFERLEN], valbuf[MAXBUFFERLEN] = {0};

while(1) { 
    sin_size =(socklen_t) sizeof(their_addr);
    new = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if((numbytes = recv(new, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) < 0){
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d\n", numbytes);

        for(line = 0; line < numbytes; ++line){
            printf("Byte#%d = ",line);
            for(bitcounter = 0; bitcounter < 8; bitcounter++){
                printf("%d ", (buffer[line] >> bitcounter)&1);
            }
            printf("\n");
            switch(line){
                case 0: switch(buffer[line]) {
                            case 1: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*D*/ break;
                            case 2: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*S*/ break;
                            case 3: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*SD*/ break;
                            case 4: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*G*/ break;
                            case 5: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*GD*/ break;
                            case 6: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*SG*/ break;
                            case 7: command = (buffer[line]); fprintf(stdout, "line = %d, command = %d\n", line, command); /*SGD*/ break;
                            default: fprintf(stdout,"Not a valid command\n");   /*Fehlermeldung*/ break;
                }
                case 1: transid = buffer[line]; break;
                case 2: keylenMSB = buffer[line]; keylenMSB = keylenMSB << 8; break;
                case 3: keylenLSB = buffer[line]; keylen = keylenMSB|keylenLSB; ; break;
                case 4: vallenMSB = buffer[line]; vallenMSB = vallenMSB << 8; break;
                case 5: vallenLSB = buffer[line]; vallen = vallenMSB|vallenLSB; break;
                default: if(line < numbytes - vallen){
                        keybuf[line - 6] = buffer[line];
                } else if(vallen > 0){
                        valbuf[line-6-keylen] = buffer[line];       
                }
            }
        }

        switch(command){
            case 1: delete(hashtable, keybuf); /*D*/ break;
            case 2: set(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); /*S*/ break;
            case 4: get(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf);  /*G*/ break;
            case 3: set(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); delete(hashtable, keybuf); /*SD*/ break; 
            case 6: set(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); get(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); /*SG*/ break;
            case 5: get(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); delete(hashtable, keybuf); /*GD*/ break;
            case 7: set(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); get(hashtable, keybuf, valbuf); delete(hashtable, keybuf);  /*SGD*/ break;
            default: fprintf(stdout,"Unknown command.\n")/*Fehlermeldung*/; break;
        }
        buffer[0] = buffer[0]|0b00001000;
        send(new, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        for(line = 0; line < numbytes; ++line){
            printf("Sending Byte#%d = ",line);
            for(bitcounter = 0; bitcounter < 8; bitcounter++){
                printf("%d ", (buffer[line] >> bitcounter)&1);
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us which line the compiler error or warning is happening on.

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand at all (as I'd need to see the full, compilable source code to find the exact problem), but: you usually want to store the original hash with each data element, for two reasons: 1) you can then compare the full hashes before having to compare the key strings; 2) you can grow the table without recomputing all hashes. (Of course, you still use `hash % tablesize` to find out the slot in the hash table.)

Comment: @JohnZwinck see this... `(line 53)->   unsigned long hval = hash(key);`

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Maybe something wrong in `main()`? `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  at 0x40112A: main (hashserver.c:133)`, could you also show that line?

Comment: I'm guessing OP forgot to clear the `hashtable[]` pointers to NULL, before the first call to `set()`. No, wait; that would hit on the next line instead, I think. So, perhaps OP calls `set()` with `key` pointing to `buffer[]`, without initializing `buffer[]`? (Michael Walz below actually pointed this out first, I was still editing this comment when he did.)

Comment: Show how you call the `set` function. The problem is most likely the `key` parameter that points to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of char buffers in your code, are you trying to use them as the keys? For example you could initialize them like this:

```
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
```

This code simulates exactly the same behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int hash(char *str) {
  unsigned int hash = 5381;
  int c;

  while ((c = *str++))
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

  return hash % 128;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char initialized[20] = "hello";
  printf("hash(initialized) = %u\n", hash(initialized));

  char not_initialized[20];
  printf("hash(not_initialized) = %u\n", hash(not_initialized));
  return 0;
}
```